# Mean value theorem equivalence

Tags: integration, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

Is is the image correct and is the answer to part (b) of the question below also correct?

2. Consider a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.

(a) State the Mean Value Theorem for $f$ on an interval $[a, b]$.

**(b) Compute the mean value $M_k$ on the interval $[0, k], 
k > 0$ of the function $f(x)= (x- 1)(x- 3) = x^2 - 4x + 3**$

(c) Find $k > 0$ such that $M_k = 0$

(Context for my question)
Math is not my strongest suit and I have a lot of self-doubt.I wanted to confirm that both equations are the same;  I've tried to check it myself but whatever I get I doubt going back to my shaky confidence. Thanks!

[Answer to (b) and also if both equations are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f1Qc.png)

Comment: Are they the same? No. One states the average value is a value f(c) of the function. One states the slope of the tangent line is equal at a value c to the slope of the secant line.

Comment: What is true is that if $f$ has a continuous derivative on $[a,b]$, then $$\dfrac{\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx}{b-a} = \dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$$ And thus, both the Mean Value theorem for derivatives and the Mean Value theorem for integrals imply there is a $c \in [a,b]$ with $f'(c)$ equaling this value. It is not clear to me which Mean Value theorem is asked for in your problem, since $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable or integrable in it.